# How to use shortcut-key to move cursor in clion?

Tags: ide, clion, keyboard-shortcuts

Using direction key is slow when I'm coding, I want to find a method to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to move cursor.

Comment: What exactly is "ctrl + k" supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

[This is complete list of shortcuts for Clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/documentation/docs/CLion_ReferenceCard.pdf)

**Alt + F9 to Run to cursor**